# Adjust height of cardview based on the items in listview

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have a cardview as a parent layout. Inside that cardview I am inflating a listview of items. I have a fixed heigth of the cardview right now but I want to dynamically adjust the height based on the items in listview.

This is my parent xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/shelfShareLinearlayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:padding="20dp">



        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is my child view's xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/shelfShareMasterLL"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/frontalRodShareCardView"
        android:layout_width="585dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/shelfShareMasterRL"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/deleteSlefShareCard"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/shelfShareHeadingTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Frontal Rod Share"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/noFrontalRodShareCheck"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/shelfShareHeadingTextView"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/deleteSlefShareCard"

                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:text="No Frontal Rod Share" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/shelfShareProductListView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/shelfShareHeadingTextView">

            </ListView>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is how I'm inflating child view and displaying list to it:

```
ArrayList<Products> shelfShareList = new ArrayList<Products>();
final LinearLayout shelfShareLL = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.shelfShareLinearlayout);
final View shelfShareChildView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cardviewshelfshare, null);
shelfShareLL.addView(shelfShareChildView);

ListView listView = (ListView) shelfShareChildView.findViewById(R.id.shelfShareProductListView);

Cursor crs = database.rawQuery(//My query, null);

  while (crs.moveToNext()){

    shelfShareList.add(//data from query);

  }

listView.setAdapter(new ProductsAdapter(getActivity(), shelfShareList));

crs.close();
```

Comment: have you tries using height as `wrap_content` for both cardview and relative layout inside it?

Comment: I've already tried this but didn't work for me

Comment: i think you should set your cardview, relativelayout and listview height as wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

Without adding the child view xml to the parent programatically, add it in the parent xml like this:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/layout_name_of_your_child"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Then in the child layout, remove the root `LinearLayout` and make the `CardView` as root. Then make sure to change `layout_height` to `wrap_content` in the `CardView`.

Then change the `layout_height` of your `ListView` in the child xml file to `wrap_content`. This should work fine!